# Media query - change CSS as dynamic content width changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using semantic-ui and have a grid setup as follows within a tab segment:

```
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="Overall Stats">

<div class="ui internally celled stackable grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="eight wide column">
      <h4 class="ui blue header">Top Goal Scorers
        <div class="sub header">(All Age Groups)</div>
      </h4>
      <div id="showOverallGB"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="eight wide column">
      <h4 class="ui blue header">Most MoM Awards
        <div class="sub header">(All Age Groups)</div>
      </h4>
      <div id="showOverallMoM"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

In the `showOverall*` divs I add dynamically created tables. The issue I have is that the created tables can be wider than the columns they sit in which means the left hand table overlaps the right hand table (when viewing on a non-mobile device such that the grid does NOT stack). Is there a way to invoke the `stackable` part of the grid if the dynamically added tables are wider than the columns they sit in?

Edit: here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/eynnqLkk/1/
You'll need to go to the `Age Group Stats` tab and then play around with the jsfiddle boundaries. You should see something like:
[image]

Comment: Share a Fiddle.

Comment: @Geoman-Yabes- are you sure? I checked it and do not see any missing tags. Also, the tables should be horizontally aligned on larger screens. But the issue is: on certain screen sizes the tables overlap because the screen is not wide enough but the screen IS wide enough to prevent the media query to make the grid stackable.

Comment: yeah sorry.  removed my comment

Comment: @DeepakYadav You are required to show the markup/code that shows the problem here, not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: Can somebody explain the reason for the downvote? I'm curious what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add scroll bars to your tables so they won't overlap adding:

```
#showGB, #showMoM {width:100%; overflow:auto;}
```

as you can see here: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77g0ewwe/)**

Or if you want to move one behind the other when no room avaliable remove the width 50% of your container with:

```
.ui.grid > .row > [class*="eight wide"].column {width:auto !Important}
```

as you can see here: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L70gj4us/)**

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the second solution. Can you explain a bit more what it is doing? I think it just sets the width to auto, right? But then I do not understand why the CSS doesn't have that by default.

Comment: Css width by default is 100% on any block element. The problem is your `semantic`css. Is there were it adds the fixed width. in this case 50%.